# java programming dead code

Tags: java, methods

I just need someone to tell me why index++ is a dead code so I can try to fix it myself.

heres my code for one class

```
public class ManagementCompany {
    private String name;
    private String taxID;
    private Property[] properties;
    private double mgmFeePer;
    private final int MAX_PROPERTY = 5;

    public ManagementCompany(String name, String taxID, double mgmFee)
    {
        properties = new Property[MAX_PROPERTY];
        this.name = name;
        this.taxID = taxID;
        this.mgmFeePer = mgmFee;
    }

    public int getMAX_PROPERTY()
    {
        return MAX_PROPERTY;
    }
    public int addProperty(Property property)
    {
        for(int index = 0; index < properties.length; index++)
        {
            properties[index] = property;
                return (index + 1);
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

heres my other class. Not sure if it's needed though

Comment: Because you are immediately returning from inside the for-loop so there is no need to increment the index.

Comment: Why have a for loop if it never really loops?

Answer (score 2):

You have a `return` in the loop.
By unrolling the for you will see why it is dead code:

```
FOR INITIALIZATION: int index = 0;
FOR PRE-LOOP CHECK: index < properties.length

FOR BODY EXECUTION: properties[index] = property;
                    return (index + 1);

FOR POST-LOOP UPDATE: index++
```

As you can see, the `return` makes the loop terminate and exit the `for()` statement and the enclosing method. This premature termination of the loop is the cause that execution can never reach the post-loop update `index++`.

**EDIT**: I've left this answer incompleted for several hours because the server went under maintenance while I was writing.